# Calculate an integral depending on n

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

Is there a way (simple or not) to calculate the following integral?

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt[n]{1-x^n} dx$$

Thanks

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica gives an expression with hypergeometric function, so I suppose there might not be a way to calculate it simply.

Comment: It looks symmetric about 0. So you can expand the root in terms of $x$.

Comment: It is symmetric only for even $n$

Comment: @uranix +1, Ah I won't tell you the stupid mistake I made when $n\to 2m + 1$ ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For **even** values of *n*, the simple substitution $t=x^n$ will automatically yield the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), which is basically a generalization of [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).
- For **odd** values of *n*, the same basic substitution will yield a sum of complete and [incomplete beta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function). The latter can also be expressed in terms of [hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), by expanding the integrand into its [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and then switching the order of summation and integration. This last trick might also cover the “numerical methods” that you seem to mention in your post.

Answer (score 2):

$2 \text{B}(1/n, 1/n+1)/n$ where $\text{B}$ is the Beta function, if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 2):

As already said by uranix, the result involves the hypergeometric function. Without any restriction about $n$, the formula is given by $$\int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt[n]{1-x^n} \,dx=\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n};1+\frac{1}{n};(-1)^n\right)+\sqrt{\pi }\frac{
  \Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)} 4^{-1/n}$$ which is not the nicest form we could dream about.

For the case where $n$ is even, Robert Israel already gave the answer $$\int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt[n]{1-x^n} \,dx=\frac{2}{n}B\left(\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$